# How do I fix this error to take the MOOC.Fi Java Course?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, java-11

I am trying to do the MOOC.Fi course to learn how Java (new to programming).

I went through the tutorial, https://www.mooc.fi/en/installation/netbeans/#javan-asentaminen.

For Mac, for installing the JDK, I first went to https://adoptopenjdk.net/?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=hotspot, I chose "OpenJDK 11 (LTS)" and "Hot Spot". I clicked the button to "Adoptium has moved to - adoptium.net" and downloaded the "jdk-11.0.15+10 Temurin AQAvit logo April 26, 2022 - MacOS - x64 - JDK -186 MB .pkg".
I then downloaded the TMCBeans from this link in the tutorial, "https://download.mooc.fi/tmcbeans/installers/tmcbeans_1.4.0_installer.dmg".

I dragged the file icon to the application folder and then after it finished downloading to the application folder, I ejected "tmcbeans", per the instructions.

After clicking on "tmcbeans" application in the applications folder, I got an error saying that it won't open from an unidentified developer, so I allowed it to open by going to Settings>Security and Privacy>Allowing "tmcbeans" top open on the general page.

Finally, when I launch the Netbeans app again, tmcbeans, the following error message pops up:

> The JDK is missing and is required to run some NetBeans modules. Please
> use the --jdkhome command line option to specify a JDKinstallation or
> see http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqRunningOnJreformore information.

Using this tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ysgBcbSfhg to fix the issue, I went into applications>right click on tmcbeans>click on "show package contents">open "contents" folder>open "resources" folder>open "tmcbeans" folder>open "etc" folder>open "tmcbeans.conf" with Textedit application> changed bottom to:
#jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-11.jdk/Contents/Home"

Hit Save in Textedit > Closed TextEdit > Restarted TMCBeans
I get the same error. What am I doing wrong? What alternatives can I use to TMCBeans that has a JDK incorporated into it, so I can get through the course (i.e. could I use Intellij)? I am a complete novice in anything programming and am just trying to make it past the installation step.